# Windows Media Services streaming (using RSTP or HTTP) to Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-2.2-froyo

Is it possible to stream video to an Android device by using [Windows Media Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Services)? Which protocol should I use between RTSP and HTTP?  Actually, I have a video file (MP4 format) at a server and I want to stream video files to an Andriod device.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Android does not support adaptive streaming. I searched for some methods a while ago, but Android does not support any of them. No streaming via Windows Media Server, no support for Flash Media Server and [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) also does not work. The last one would be the best solution since it does not depend on proprietary protocols - but unfortunately it uses a different container format MPEG-TS and a playlist file M3U8 which Android does not understand at the moment. There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9965) for this - you might want to stare it. ;-)

That said, I would recommend you to just upload the MP4 file to an HTTP server and play it via the HTTP url. If it doesn't play, you have to add some extra streaming information by hinting it - e.g. with [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box):

```
mp4box -hint <filename>
```

Have fun. :-)